# State counting in the d = 1+2, $\cal{N} = 2$ vector multiplet

Tags: supersymmetry, field-theory, degrees-of-freedom, superspace-formalism

The question is from Box 8.2, page 282 of the book "Gauge Gravity Duality" by Ammon and Erdmenger. The link to the specific page from Google Books is [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=OG0GBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=martin%20ammon%20johanna%20erdmenger&pg=PA282#v=onepage&q=282&f=false).

According to the authors, a $\mathcal{N} = 2$ vector superfield includes a vector potential $A_\mu$, a real scalar field $\sigma$, two real (Majorana) gauginos, and an auxiliary real scalar field $D$, all in the adjoint representation of the gauge group.

I am not sure how the counting works:

- Vector potential $A_\mu$ has $(3-2) = 1$ (bosonic) degree of freedom, as a gauge field in $d = 1 + 2$ dimensions.
- A real scalar field has $1$ (bosonic) degree of freedom.
- Two real Majorana gauginos have $2 \times 2^{(3-1)/2}$ (real) fermionic degrees of freedom, i.e. $4$ fermionic degrees of freedom.
- An auxiliary real field has $1$ bosonic degree of freedom.

The number of fermionic and bosonic components do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing an on-shell counting for an off-shell multiplet. The off-shell vector multiplet has

$\sigma [1], A_{\mu} [2], D[1], \lambda [4]$

thus $4+4$ degrees of freedom. The on-shell vector multiplet consists of the scalar $\sigma$, the vector $A_\mu$ and the Dirac fermion $\lambda$. In that case, the counting is

$\sigma [1], A_{\mu} [1], \lambda [2]$

so you have $2+2$ degrees of freedom.